# Installing Qt on Mac OSX Lion/make is missing

Tags: qt, macos, makefile, osx-lion

I have a problem installing the Qt SDK on my mac. I have had 4.7.4 installed before and it worked. I've updated to Lion and I could not compile any projects. I read then for that I have to switch to 4.8 beta and tried that but during the installation I got the error that gcc could not be installed.

I then figured out that the make command was missing due I had Xcode installed. I then re-installed Xcode (4.1) but it is still missing.

I'm not a unix guru, but I think make missing is not normal, even for a mac, so I hope somebody can give me a hint, what I can do to fix that problem?

Comment: What's the output of `gcc --version` when you run the command in Terminal app?

Comment: -bash: gcc: command not found

I tried to add:
/Developer/usr/lib/gcc
to the PATH but does not work either

Comment: PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: `gcc` is usually found in `/usr/bin` (in fact, Apple now ships `llvm-gcc` but it doesn't matter for your purpose). Did you really install Xcode? If you grabbed it via AppStore (yeah, what else now!), you should install it manually (look into your `/Applications` folder for the install app).

Comment: you want to tell me he didn't install it, when I clicked 'install'? Yeah, make sense, but there is a 'Install Xcode' in the application-folder so I guess, it'll work, but I will give a feedback.
Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: @Robe That's part of AppStore funniest features :-) Yes, you need to install it after AppStore downloaded it for you (then remove the 4+ Go install app).

Comment: Ok he is compiling now it seems. Had some issues with macPorts. After removing from the path it seems to work now. So I hope, I'm the only stupid that didn't got that...

Thank's for helping me.
Greets, Rob

Comment: I had to vote this up... I had the exact same problem. I simply assumed that clicking install actually installed the app. Good grief.

Answer (score 6):

When XCode is installed,

install the qt 4.8 with brew like this: `brew install qt --build-from-source` (You need brew: [install brew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation)).

Than install Qt Creator from here: http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools.

Copy the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/` into your `QtSDK 13.05.01/Desktop/Qt/` location. I made this with terminal's `cp -r`.

Than from Qt: "Preferences Panel" -> "Qt4" add manually the qMake Location just copied.
click "Projects edit "Build configurations" and set in the Qt version "Qt 4.8.0 (4.8.0)" or something like that.

Delete all the older qt's output folder (like Release and Debug), and clic on the Run Button.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer. Remember, it's considered both helpful and polite to accept answers as correct if they've address your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar message building 4.7.3 from the .zip source file. I believe you get this error if file endings are incorrect.

It worked to to build from the .tar.gz source file, but not from the .zip file.

Maybe that'll help?